# Filter grouped products in layered navigation by their associated configurable products's attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, grouped-products

My category page contains only "grouped products" and I want to filter them in layered navigation by their associated (configurable) products's attributes.

As I understand now grouped product itself has no configurable attributes. Layered Navigation looks into attributes of the parent product.

I can't find any solution to this problem, maybe someone can help me with it?